# Android MapFragment as custom control in MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm working on a project in which I can use MapFragment or SupportMapFragment as a custom control.
I tried to mix custom control([N-18](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1LhXdCTsn4)) and Fraggle([N-26](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQT3_WXQQr0)) tutorial but I can't make it work.

My Custom Control Class:

```
public class CustomMapView : MvxFragment
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.CustomMapViewLayout, null);
    }
}
```

My CustomMapViewLayout.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

In the FirstView.axml I reference the CustomMapView:

```
<cc.CustomMapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

(I use the ViewNamespaceAbbreviations in the Setup.cs)

When I try to deploy I  get these errors:

MvxBind:Error View Type Not Found - cc.CustomMapView (I'm sure the namespace is correct)
Android.Views.InflateException:Loading...

Is there anybody who managed to solve this kind problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, fragments have to be used within FragmentActivity parents and have to be loaded either using the `fragment` xml tag or using one of the (support) fragment manager methods for dynamic loading within a parent viewgroup.

The Mvx code which is reporting `View Type Not Found - cc.CustomMapView` definitely won't work - it's looking for a class which inherits Android `View` in that namespace, not looking for a `Fragment`.

There may be ways to write more 'dynamic' fragment xml code - but none of the mvvmcross contributors have unearthed any of these yet. For now, I think you'll have to use the Fragments more 'conventionally' - like the ways shown in the [N=26 sample](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQT3_WXQQr0)