# MvvmCross Android Google Map Fragment within Another Fragment

Tags: google-maps, android-fragments, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Referring to the 2 samples "FragmentSample" and "N41 - Map", I am trying to put a google map fragment inside a tab fragment without success.

This is the code that I implement the map fragment:

```
 public class MapTabFragment
: BaseRouteTabFragment
{
    private MarkerSet _Markers;
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                      Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        var binding = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.tabs_map, null);

        var mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) ChildFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map);
        _Markers = new MarkerSet(mapFragment.map);

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MapTabFragment, MapTabViewModel>();
        set.Bind(_Markers)
           .For(m => m.ItemsSource)
           .To(vm => vm.RouteMarkers);
        set.Apply();

        return binding;
    }
```

.....

and the axml for the tab:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The main difference in my code when comparing to the sample is the class inherited from BaseRouteTabFragment (from MvxFragment), and using ChildFragmentManager.FindFragmentById instead of SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById. With this change,

- "mapFragment.map" has compile error
  "'SupportMapFragment' does not contain a definition for 'map' and no
  extension method 'map' accepting a first argument of type
  'SupportMapFragment' could be found".

What is the proper way to retrieve the map, or it is not possible to put a map fragment inside another fragment but activity only?

While searching for a solution, I found there was a similar question from a few years ago 
[Android MapFragment as custom control in MvvmCross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079793/android-mapfragment-as-custom-control-in-mvvmcross), with an answer from Stuart that it is not possible at that time. He mentioned that there may be some other ways to handle but not being touched by any mvx contributors. I wonder there is any solution now.

I could easily switch my solution using tab activity instead of tab fragments. However, my solution will not have any chance to use hamburger menu anymore if my understanding is correct.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: In your `OnCreateView` you are returning on the second line preventing any further code execution and getting the warning "unreachable code detected". Move your code above the return, or place the inflated view in to a variable and return it at the end of your method if you required access to the view.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the silly mistake. It has been modified as your suggestion to keep the binding and return by the end of the code. The binding layout was wrong and corrected too. It solve the "unreachable code detected".  Error "SupportMapFragment" does not contain a definition for 'map' remains.